# Correctly organize time series data on InfluxDB

Tags: python, time-series, influxdb

I'm super new to time series database and I've just approached the use of InfluxDB with Python.

I'm trying to understand **what's the best way to organize data**.

The system I need to monitor is basically a **cluster of sensors**. The data acquisition will be in real-time but not 24/7. **The user will be able to start/stop the acquisition** and every acquisition must be grouped.

Having read the documentation and the examples with Python my idea of gerarchy organization is something like

```
- Measurement: My Cluster Sensor
-- Tag: My Acquisition #1
--- Field: My Sensor #1
--- Field: My Sensor #2
...... etc
```

A similar python code would be

```
point = (
    Point("MyClusterSensor")
    .tag("Acquisition", var_acquisitionNumber)
    .field("Sensor1", var_sensor1,"Sensor2",var_sensor2)
  )
write_api.write(bucket=MyBucket, org="abc@gmail.com", record=point)
```

Does it make sense and it is in line with the idea of InfluxDB and how it should be used?

Is there a better way to store the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the right choice but `field` is used as

```
point = (
    Point("MyClusterSensor")
    .tag("Acquisition", var_acquisitionNumber)
    .field("Sensor1", var_sensor1)
    .field("Sensor2",var_sensor2)
  )
write_api.write(bucket=MyBucket, org="abc@gmail.com", record=point)
```